# How to instantiate a Kotlin class extending a Java class with different field variables than in derived class

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

I am a Kotlin noob and want to know how to instantiate a Kotlin class extending a Java class when the base class has different field variables than the derived class.

In the current project I am working on, we have a design where all the entity classes extend a base class that defines common columns required for each entity i.e. an identifier, version, creationDate, createdBy etc.

This base class is in Java and I am defining my entities in Kotlin and extending this base class.

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, doNotUseGetters = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Audited
@ToString
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(
        name = "identifier",
        nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "uuid"
    )
    private UUID identifier;
    @Version
    @Column(
        name = "vrsn",
        nullable = false
    )
    private long version;
.....
other common fields
}
```

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "my_entity")
class MyEntity(
    val identityDocumentNumber: String?,
    val startDate: Instant?,
    val endDate: Instant?,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val enum: AnEnum,
    val email: String,
) : BaseEntity()
```

I am having trouble with unit testing when I am trying to create a mock instance of my entity class with a mock value for the identifier.
I cannot of course pass the identifier in MyEntity constructor because identifier is not defined in MyEntity

```
private val MOCK_MY_ENTITY =
MyEntity(
  identifier = MOCK_ANALYST_NAME, //Error - cannot find the parameter with this name
  identityDocumentNumber = null,
  startDate = Instant.now(),
  ......
```

If I try to use the scoping function then I get the error **val cannot be reassigned**

```
private val MOCK_MY_ENTITY =
MyEntity(
  identityDocumentNumber = null,
  startDate = Instant.now(),
  ......
).apply { 
  identifier = MOCK_ANALYST_UID //Error - val cannot be reassigned
}
```

If MyEntity was a Java class then I could have annotated it with lombok

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
```

and then do something like the following

```
    private val My_ENTITY: MyEntity
        get() = MyEntity.builder()
            .identifier(MOCK_IDENTIFIER_UUID)
            .identityDocumentNumber(MOCK_DOCUMENT_NUMBER)
            ........
            ).build()
```

However, I do not know how to do this in Kotlin.

I have looked around and tried a few things but couldn't get anything working. Any suggestion, please? Thanks.

Comment: About the `val cannot be reassigned` - is there a setter in Java for the `identifier` property? Or is this value injected via reflection all the time?

Comment: @Joffrey, no there is no setter for `identifier` property. BaseEntity is annotated with lombok annotations for a builder and no/all args constructor. Sorry, I had missed out this detail earlier, I have edited the question and have added it.